# Chrome Dev Tools Snippet - Input in Text Field Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to test a simple snippet in Chrome Dev Tools to automate the pasting of a string of text into an input field on a website.

Website Link: https://tronscan.org/#/

The goal of the script is to input a string into the search field at the top of the page labeled "Search by Address/TXn Hash/Token/Block" and then press the search button.

However, when I try the script below, the input string immediately disappears and the search is then unable to register the inputted value:

```
function inputtext(){
    var desiredstring = "TV9QitxEJ3pdiAUAfJ2QuPxLKp9qTTR3og";
    var contractsearchfield = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control p-2 border-0 box-shadow-none newSearchInput")[0];
    contractsearchfield.value = desiredstring;
    setTimeout(search, 1000);
}
function search(){
    var searchbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("btn box-shadow-none index_page_search")[0].click();
}
inputtext();
```

(The warning message reading "Sorry, the search string you entered could not be found." will be shown).

This is the text input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control p-2 border-0 box-shadow-none newSearchInput" placeholder="Search by Address/TXn Hash/Token/Block" value="" style="font-size: 14px; min-width: 260px; height: 48px;">
```

Is there anything incorrect about this method above or is something in the website overriding the script? If so, is there any way around it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like they are overriding it somehow. Might be a security feature. If you do the same thing on the search bar on this page, it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to switch to the correct page with:
window.location.href = 'https://tronscan.org/#/address/TV9QitxEJ3pdiAUAfJ2QuPxLKp9qTTR3og';